# Page Breaks in a Report made in VB2012

Tags: vb.net, ssrs-2008

I made a report in the VS2012 IDE (VB2012) as shown.

[image]
I set the property of the KeepTogather table to True.
A run time in view within ReportViewer the report you see everything and scroll it all.
I then set the horizontal orientation in SetPage and reduced the margins to 5 millimeters. 
But when I go to print, I print a blank page between them.
How can I have the report printed continuously without white pages being printed?
Thank you for your precious help as always.

Comment: try to setup margins also in Printer prop... it may be less than your 5mm

Comment: try to decrease size (high, width) of your table.. play with that.. I resolved many problems like that with reports just with playin with size.. It may be case, one part of table wont fit to page, so print blank page instead.. Also, please, try to answer me in english language only..

Comment: Thank you is the browse that or the system that translates into automatic in Italian